# Highstock Time series not formatting on scatter tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

When you have defined the xAxis as a 'dateTime' type the tooltip should be aware of this as the 'point.x' value and convert it to the DateTime format.

```
xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Time Range'
        },
        type: "datetime"
    },
```

I would expect the tooltip to provide me with the Readable Datetime

http://jsfiddle.net/egf4vbfL/6/

As you can see the X-Axis is correct in that it uses the Time rage however when you view the default tooltip you get the epoch time.

I know you can format this using 'point.key' etc but for every other chart time it works as expected.

Is this a bug with highstock or some expected behavior ?

If expected can someone point out why ?

Note : Same `issue` applies to highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

Its reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3552) so please stay on track with this thread.

Comment: Thanks @sebastian it was me who reported it!

Comment: Ha! interesting, I see another nickname, so I dont link both of them ;)

Answer (score 0):

With a `datetime` axis, the x-value in your series data should be a Date. As in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/egf4vbfL/32/

This will show an ugly formatted date. To show a nicely formated date, you should be able to use `tooltip.xDateFormat` but that does not work. You can use forced date grouping, is a describe in my own question: [Highchart / Highstock shows unformated tooltip lable when data grouping enabled but not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563966/highchart-highstock-shows-unformated-tooltip-lable-when-data-grouping-enabled)