# Highchart / Highstock shows unformated tooltip lable when data grouping enabled but not used

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When using data grouping with datetime in Highcharts / Highstock, there seems to be a problem with the formatting of the tooltip label.

When data grouping is actually applied (i.e. when there would be so many datapoints in the chart that the width of each of them would fall below `dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth`), the label for the tooltip is created using the `dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats` configuration option.

But when grouping is not applied, for example when zooming so much that each datapoint width is above the limit, the label for the tooltip is not formatted at all. In the case of a datetime axis, the raw string value of the date will be displayed (same as `date.toString()`). Setting a `tooltip.xDateFormat` does not help.

This might also be the case when data grouping is disabled.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/v3obp9h3/

Hoover over the data and checkout the tooltip: it shows a nicely formatted datetime range.

Zoom in by selecting part of the graph until you see the data for quarter of an hour. This is the basic ungrouped data. The tooltip now shows the data badly formatted.

**workaround**
I managed to work around this by making sure grouping is always used. My raw data is for 15 minutes, so I make sure `dataGrouping.units` contains 15 minute blocks. Then I set `dataGrouping.forced` to `true`. This feels like a bad trick because when the incoming data would become 5 minutes blocks, the graph would  never display the raw data.

Is there a better way to format the x-value in the tooltip when dateGrouping is enabled but not used?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?  I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: Will do, sorry for the delay

Comment: I have rewritten the question and meanwhile found some stuff out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this issue is that you use *moment.js* dates instead of **timestamps** as x values for your points.

I replaced *moment.js* with standard `Date.UTC` and `Date.now` functions (they return timestamps) and everything works as it should:

```
 //create timedata
 var data = [];
 var m = Date.UTC(2016);
 var until = Date.now();

 while (m < until) {

   data.push({
     x: m,
     y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
   });
   m += 15 * 60 * 1000;
 }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/dLq34dkt/

**Docs reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes (*Datetime* paragraph)

Comment: This is the correct answer, the axis should be in unix timestamps. I still use moment, but instead of doing `toDate()`, I do `unix()`. See https://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/v3obp9h3/10/

I will check the docs again, because it only said it would internally use timestamp, and the Highcharts examples use Date. But this helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: Well.... there is still a problem, because the X axis wants us to use timestamp, but the Highstock Navigator and Bands need date objects... So my solution forcing grouping even at the lowest zoom level still works better...

Comment: Highcharts always uses timestamps for `datetime` axes (even in navigator and bands). Could you provide the examples that you mentioned as the ones that use dates instead of timestamps?

Comment: Hi Kamil, thanks for thinking along. I think it is in setExtremes: https://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/v3obp9h3/13/

I do a setExtremes on the X axis of the main chart, and it does not seem to matter wether I use .toDate() of .unix()..

Comment: It is not an official demo and it doesn't work if I provide different dates: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/nn0sktef/ Maybe it does work in some cases but it's just a coincidence.

Comment: I found the problem! I use setExtremes and that one does not work correctly with dates or unix timestamps, but uses windows timestamps...

Does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/v3obp9h3/14/
Works: https://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/v3obp9h3/15/

Check the * 1000. How weird is that?!

Comment: This one works allright, using windows timestamps everywhere: https://jsfiddle.net/Jelmerjellema/v3obp9h3/16/